# Woocommerce : Why do I get parrent category of a product and not current child category?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to make a discount category. But on some categories I get parent category id and not the child id.

I tried getting term_id of product cat like this :

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
$term_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
```

and this version is not a good solution for me:

```
$category = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $category->term_id;
```

So far I'm stuck at this:

```
function category_percentage($product)
{
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
    $term_id = $terms[0]->term_id; // I belive here is the problem

    $discount_category = get_term_meta($term_id, 'discount_category', true);

    return $discount_category;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_sale_price_for_category', 10, 2 );
function custom_sale_price_for_category( $price, $product )
{

    if(category_percentage($product)<=0) return $price;

    $price *= ( 1 - category_percentage($product)/100 );

    return $price;
}
```

in category_percentage($product) function I want to get the current category of the product, but for some reason in some categories I get the parrent category, and yes, I do have the parent category checked for the product as well. But I have it like that for all the products and still get different results when I recive the current cat id.

Comment: when you try `$terms[0]->term_id` you say that the very first term should set. I think you should set a loop for terms and check if they have child and child and ... till the loop say no there is no child. so this is exactly what term you need (as i understand from your question).

Comment: I tried that as well but if I have ex parent with child 1 ->grandchild 1 and child 2->grandchild 2 . And I need grandchild 1, the loop will give me grandchild 2. I don’t know what condition to set to get grandchild 1.

Comment: maybe you can set custom_field for that solution. save the term id into that and you will simply get that

Comment: what use of that? the scope of this function is to get the custom field meta that is set for the category

Comment: can i check how do you prefer to get `grandchild 1` as you commented above?

Comment: I don’t know how to get grandchild 1, that is the problem, try to make a 3 lv categori with 3 children and all 3 children to have 3 grandchildren and try to get the first grandchildren of that category. I have 2 category like that and one of it dose give me the correct result and the other dose not. But both are the same that is why I’m confused.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children read here to get children. if `is_array` or `!wp_error()` then get the first one `$term[0]`